# How to reset an entire DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to be able to reset my DataFrame to its original state whenever I need to.

I tried declaring 2 DataFrame variables (say `df_1` and `df_2`) with the exact same data so I can edit `df_1`, then reset it to it's original form (inside `df_2`) whenever I need to.

I tried doing this in one of my projects but for some reason it doesn't work. Here's the basic idea:

```
# Import dataset
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = 'latin-1'))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = 'latin-1'))

# Random edits to dataset
df_1.drop("whatever")

# Reset to original state (This doesn't work.)
df_1 = df_2
```

For some reason, after `df_1 = df_2`, all edits I make to `df_1` are also done to `df_2`, they're weirdly connected somehow.

Is there any way to implement what I want? Thanks!

Comment: This is because your second copy of the dataframe is a shallow copy, meaning the object that represents `df_2` points to the same data in memory as `df_1`. You need to make a deep copy by calling `df_2=df._1.copy()`

Comment: The TLDR is what @kalgoritmi says, use `.copy`. But to add, a lot of times issues like this go unnoticed because _many_ of the pandas operations explicitly force the creation of new objects. So even if you don't explicitly force a deep copy the next line being `df_2 = ...` might itself break the link between `df_1` and `df_2` so you'd happen to get lucky with future changes to `df_2` no longer affecting `df_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `df.copy()`

```
# Import dataset
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = 'latin-1'))
df_2 = df_1.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `df_1=df_2` what happens is that both df_1 and df_2 point to the same memory address, so what you can do is use `df_2=df_1.copy()`(as @Ade_1 rightly pointed out) as now df_2 will get it's own copy of the df_1 dataframe and both are independent(points to 2 different memory address), the same thing happens when you deal with any objects, for example you could try doing the same in case of python list.